# SLComposeViewController - SLServiceTypeTwitter, sound&video

Tags: ios, twitter, social-networking, attachment, slcomposeviewcontroller

When using SLComposeViewController/SLServiceTypeTwitter, is it possible to attach sound or video?
With an object instanciated as follow:

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
```

I can use methods like addURL or addImage, but nothing like addSound or addVideo that I can see.

Is there a different way that one can use?

Answer (score 2):

Twitter doesn't support audio or video natively.

That's why third-party services such as ["Twitpic"](http://twitpic.com) "TwitVid" (aka [Telly](http://telly.com)) exist.

Which hopefully explains why SLComposeViewController doesn't support adding sounds or videos at this point in time.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info. Using SLServiceTypeFacebook though raises the same issue. Is it for the same reason? And is there a way around?